# Get-Package not recognized

Tags: powershell

When using `Get-Package` I get the below response:

> Get-package is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

I've searched using `Get-Command -Name *Get*` and don't see `Get-Package`.

Does it need to be installed separately? I wouldn't have thought it did.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using? The [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn890704.aspx) states that the command is available for PowerShell 5.0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Ah! I'm only on version 2.0!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn890704.aspx) `Get-Package` isn't available prior to PowerShell v5.